# Get more than 1000 observation for View() function

Tags: r, view, rstudio

I'm working with RStudion and when I use the View() command I can only see the first 1000 rows.
Is it possible to get more than 1000 rows ? or less than 1000 rows ? is it possible to get a range observation like observation in 500 : 1000 ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can happen:

Let's say that you have a data.frame called df which has 2000 rows and 2 columns. To view all of them you need to explicitly type on the console:

```
utils::View(df) #however this will open a new separate window to view all the records.
```

In order to view just 500:1000 records of the data.frame just do:

```
utils::View(df[500:1000,]) #i.e. use the standard way of slicing the data.frame in the function.
```

Hope this helps.